# How to add a space between the frame of an image and the image itself?

Tags: spacing, graphics, framed

I have an image in my document and I am trying to add a space between the frame of the image and the image itself. I tried to search but I didn't find results serve the purpose. The following code to insert an image:

```
    \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            \frame{\includegraphics [height=12cm,width=14cm]{SystemDesign}}
            \caption{Image}
            \label{fig:SystemDesign}
    \end{figure}
```

But my figure installed from a software that crop it exactly around the entities included in the image, I tried different solutions and the last one is to add a space between the image and the frame in LaTeX. So I am not sure if there is a way to approach that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `\frame` is the wrong way as it does not add any separation between the content and the frame. If you want to have a separation then use `\fbox` instead where the separation can be adjusted using the length `\fboxsep`. The frame line width is adjustable by the length `\fboxrule`.

However, an easier way is to load the `adjustbox` package with the `export` option and simply use the `fbox` key with two space separated arguments for the line width and separation distance.

Then you should replace `\centering` with the `center` key so the image is also centered without warnings if its width is larger than the text width.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
        \includegraphics [height=12cm,width=14cm,fbox=0.5pt 10pt,center]{example-image}
        \caption{Image}
        \label{fig:SystemDesign}
\end{figure}
```

Note that you can generate the *whole* figure construct including the `H` placement with a single `adjustbox` command:

```
\adjustimage{height=12cm,width=14cm,fbox=0.5pt 10pt,center,captionbelow={Image},label={fig:mylabel},nofloat=figure}{example-image}
```

This then needs the `adjustbox` package but not necessarily the `export` option any more.

---

Full code example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% also loaded by adjustbox
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just for example text
\begin{document}
\lipsum

    \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics [height=12cm,width=14cm,fbox=0.5pt 10pt,center]{example-image}
            \caption{Image}
            \label{fig:SystemDesign}
    \end{figure}

\lipsum
\clearpage
\lipsum

\adjustimage{height=12cm,width=14cm,fbox=0.5pt 10pt,center,captionbelow={Image},label={fig:mylabel},nofloat=figure}{example-image}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is will do the job:

```
\begin{figure}[H]

                \centering
                \setlength{\fboxsep}{10pt}%
                \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.5pt}%
                \fbox{\includegraphics[height=12cm,width=15.5cm]{SystemDesign}}
                \caption{Image}
                \label{fig:SystemDesign}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: The code does not use any feature of `adjustbox`, so the package is actually not needed. There is a way to do this with `adjustbox` with less number of lines, though.

Comment: I will edit the code, thank you @MartinScharrer